# How do I import a .graph file in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deserialization

I am looking for some easily available models to experiment with.

I have downloaded resnet_v2_152_2017_04_14.tar.gz from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim but after unpacking I get a checkpoint file and two .graph files, eval.graph and train.graph. They seem to be json. How do I import such files in Tensorflow?

Here is `head eval.graph`:

```
node { 
    name: "global_step"
    op: "Variable"   attr {
    key: "_output_shapes"
    value {
      list {
        shape {
        }
      }
    }   }   attr {
    key: "container"
    value {
      s: ""
    }   }   attr {
    key: "dtype"
```

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40305996/open-tensorflow-graph-from-file) should solve your problem.

Comment: @Vishal Looks good. Unfortunately, I am getting "Op type not registered SSTableReader". I guess this was exported with an incompatible version of TF or similar, right?